# How do I convert files with ffmpeg through the command line?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I do know how to actually convert the files, I don't know if the input and output should include the path of the file or just the file itself - do I write it like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ext1 output.ext2
```

or like this:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Path\input.ext1 C:\Path\output.ext2
```

Comment: Have you tried it? bet it makes no difference. What is more important with ffmpeg is the order of the parameter you pass. If you mixes up something, ffmpeg will tell you. Now, i'feel like flaging this question as it's not really programming related.

Comment: So does FFMPEG scan for every single directory looking for a file with said name?